# Settings Sync Issue

Tags: visual-studio-code

I had set up a very basic set of settings on one of my machines, and then when I got back to my main machine I set up in-depth settings that do everything I want. When I log in to any machine now, it attempts to sync the settings from M1(Machine 1), whereas I want M2 to be the default. All I have managed to do so far is revert the settings on M2 to use its local copy instead of the cloud settings. Is there any way to set my M2 setup as the default?

Answer (score 1):

Settings Sync would update the settings on both M1 and M2 to the newest ones. M1 settings are therefore applied because M1 was the last to update them.

There is no way to make M2 the single point of truth, but you can change the settings again on M2 and those will become the new shared config.

To make this easier, open the Sync Activity panel and revert the updates you don't need in one click.
Execute `>Settings Sync: Focus on Sync Activity (Remote) View` for the remote setting updates, or `>Settings Sync: Focus on Sync Activity (Local) View` for to see updates on the current machine.